# Spring boot to handle both http and HTTPS requests

Tags: android, spring, ssl, spring-boot, https

I want to add SSL onto the connections to my spring boot server. So far I have an Arduino, an app and a mongodb database connected to the server and making requests to it. All the communication is HTTP. I plan on making everything under HTTPS but I want to know if it'll be possible for the server to handle both http and HTTPS connection simultaneously because I plan on first implementing SSL between the app and the server and leaving the rest under http.

I am using Spring boot.

I'll research how viable it is to add SSL to the arduino but I'd like to know if a server is possible for handling both Https and http requests e.g. arduino sending requests using http and Android sending requests using https.. Because I plan on adding SSL altogether but for the time being, I'll try and have SSL from the Android app to sever will as I think that'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find better to use a *reverse proxy* for that. My favourite is [NGINX](https://nginx.org/en/docs/). Apart from securing a connection, it can also handle load-balancing, failover, HTTP -> HTTPS redirect and many more.

For generating an SSL certificate, you can use [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

Answer (score 0):

use Following code for hohandling https and http

```
if (requestUrl.getProtocol().equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
        setHostVerifier();
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sc.init(null,
                new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllX509TrustManager() },
                new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
        .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        urlconnection = (HttpsURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();
    } else {
        urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestUrl.openConnection();`enter code here`
    }
```

Comment: I tried with this code, but cannot find `setHostVerifier();` and `new TrustAllX509TrustManager()`. May I know where i can find them?  In addition, how can I redirect it to different SpringBoot controller?